# Copy a book with highlights from iPad to computer

Tags: ipad, pdf, books

I read PDFs on my iPad so that I can easily highlight them. However, I am unable to find out how to easily copy that PDFs (with the highlights) back to my computer. Please note that I am new to Apple devices and I normally use a Linux laptop.

Basically what I struggle with is to browse files on the iPad and to copy them. What I tried:

- I connected a cable to my computer and I set it up on the iPad that the computer is trusted. However, the file browser only shows the DCIM folder (containing photos from the camera). How can I browse all the other folders? And in which folder are the books (which are managed in iBooks) stored?
- I also tried to transfer the file via my server by having an HTML form where I upload the file so that I can download it from my computer. However, when I hit the BROWSE button on an HTML form, I again struggle to view the full contents of the iPad's hard drive. I only see a tiny selection including the camera and downloads.

So basically my question is how can I browse the full contents of the iPad's hard drive, either when connecting through a usb cable or when hitting BROWSE FILE in a browser. Or if there are simpler ways of copying files that I don't see, please let me know.

When I tried to google this, there are all kinds of tutorials about installing itunes and other software to sync devices, but I am not looking to sync devices, I just want to copy a single file without additional software.

I am using iPadOS 15.

Comment: Your post is slightly confusing and appears to include multiple questions which is not encouraged on this site. To summarize, you have a laptop running on Linux and you wish to transfer some PDF files with highlights and annotations from Apple Books on your iPad to your laptop. Is this accurate?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion,but yes that is indeed correct. My question is how to get them easily copied to the computer by any of the ways outlined above (cable, or uploading them to a website).